# ASP.NET/C# Where should I declare the Session using Property?

Tags: asp.net, session

NET Experts,

I got an ASP.NET MVP (Model View Presenter) application, where I am using GenMaster.Master (Master Page), Metadata.aspx (Start Page), Global.asax etc.

I am accessing the `Session["EncryptedQuery"]` in both  GenMaster.Master (Master Page) and Metadata.aspx (Start Page).

Our Session declaration convention is to use property as follows:

```
public string EncryptedQuery
{
   get
    {
       object SessionObject = Session["EncryptedQuery"];
       return (SessionObject == null) ? String.Empty : (string)SessionObject;
    }
   set
    {
        Session["EncryptedQuery"] = value;
    }
}
```

Now, where should I declare this Session property to access it in Master as well as all the content pages? And I do not want to assign/retrive  to/from  `Session["EncryptedQuery"]` direcly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A MasterPage is implemented as a Child Control of your Page.  You should be able to access it using `Page.Session` from the MasterPage.

I just noticed you may have been asking is where to *assign* the property, rather than where to *declare* it.  So, if you're asking what is the best practice as far as where to initialize Session data, then the answer is going to be the [`PostAcquireRequestState` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication_events.aspx) of the `HttpApplication` class.  You can declare this in either your Global.asax, or wire it up with a custom HTTP module.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of strategy works well and allows for session data access from anywhere in the site in a strongly typed manner.

```
public static class SessionData
{
    private const string ENCRPYTED_QUERY = "ENCRPYTED_QUERY";
    public static string EncrpytedQuery
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
                return HttpContext.Current.Session[ENCRPYTED_QUERY] as string;

            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[ENCRPYTED_QUERY] = value;
        }
    }

    //add more down here...
}
```